# How to use `filter` on Map instance in Kotlin?

Tags: java, functional-programming, gson, kotlin

I see that [`#filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) is defined on `Map`, but I am not able to figure out how to use it. Anyone care to share an example?

I have a deeply nested TreeMap instance (`TreeMap<String, Map<String, Map<*, *>>>`) and I want to `filter/find` the first (which is the only in the domain) top-level key that has a certain characteristics associated with something deeper in the value.

Here's how the data looks like:

```json
{
  "i1": {
    "aliases": {}
  },
  "i2": {
    "aliases": {}
  },
  "i3": {
    "aliases": {}
  },
  "i4": {
    "aliases": {
      "alias-im-looking-for": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I have this following non-functional code which solves it right now:

```
val indexToAliasMappingType = LinkedTreeMap<String, Map<String, Map<*, *>>>()
val indexToAliasMappings = Gson().fromJson(response.jsonString, indexToAliasMappingType.javaClass)

var currentIndexName = ""
for ((index, aliasMappings) in indexToAliasMappings) {
    val hasCurrentAlias = aliasMappings.get("aliases")?.containsKey(alias)
    if (hasCurrentAlias != null && hasCurrentAlias) {
        currentIndexName = index
    }
}

return currentIndexName
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like what you need is the key part of the first entry that matches your criteria. Something like this (single line intentional) should help:

```
val currentIndexName = indexToAliasMappings.filterValues { it["aliases"]?.containsKey(alias) ?: false }.keys.firstOrNull() ?: ""
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot invoke `firstOrNull` on the map itself, but you can invoke it on its `entries` set:

```
 val currentIndexName = indexToAliasMappings.entries.firstOrNull {
     it.value["aliases"]?.containsKey(alias) == true
 }?.key
```

`firstOrNull` iterates through map entries and stops on a first entry matching the predicate. No intermediate map allocations as in the variant with `filter` or `filterValues` are required here.

Answer (score 2):

`.filter`'s lambda returns a boolean for each entry in the map. If that boolean evaluates to `true`, that entry is part of the returned collection. If that boolean evaluates to `false`, that entry is filtered out.

```
val indexToAliasMapping = linkedMapOf(
    "i1" to mapOf(
        "aliases" to mapOf<Any, Any>()
    ),
    "i2" to mapOf(
        "aliases" to mapOf<Any, Any>()
    ),
    "i3" to mapOf(
        "aliases" to mapOf<Any, Any>()
    ),
    "i4" to mapOf(
        "aliases" to mapOf(
            "aliases-im-looking-for" to "my-alias"
        )
    )
)
// If you only need one, you could also use .first instead of .filter, which
// will give you a Pair<String, Map<String, Map<*, *>>> instead of a List
val allWithNonEmptyAliases: Map<String, Map<String, Map<*, *>>> = indexToAliasMapping.filter {
    it.value["aliases"]?.containsKey(alias) ?: false
}

// We use .toList() so you can get the first element (Map doesn't allow you to retrieve by index)
return allWithNonEmptyAliases.toList().first().first
```